# Specifying tmux command-prompt line

Tags: tmux

How can you specify the line where you want tmux's command prompt to appear?

I want to see the panes when executing tmux commands that require pane numbers (e.g. join-pane, etc) but as the command prompt is displayed **on top of the pane numbers**, I have to cancel it, memorize the pane number and type the command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing two things windows and panes. A window basically fills the whole terminal and is divided into several panes. The status line lists the windows with their numbers and name, which defaults to the name of the program currently running in the active pane in that window. You can modify the status line with `set status-left` or `set status-right` and use the `#P` character sequence, which displays the number of the active pane. However, I'm afraid this is as far as you can get (unless you patch tmux of course).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant panes not windows :P I've corrected my question. Too bad we can't change the behaviour.

Comment: Well, if you can program in C, you can patch the source. The problem is, that you would either have to print **into** the pane, which would collide with the application in it or add a border into which you would be able to put the number... The latter one would get a bit tricky for small window sizes. IMHO in this case the more difficult part is getting it conceptually right.